# A dimension-free upper bound for $\| X \|_{\infty}$ when $X \sim N(0,\Sigma)$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, normal-distribution, concentration-of-measure

For a $p$-dimensional random vector $X \sim N(0,\Sigma)$, it is known that with high probability
$$
\| X \|_{\max} \le C \sqrt{\log p}
$$
where $C$ is some constant possibly depending on $\Sigma$. I would like to know if there is a simple dimension free bound that generalizes this result.

For context on a related problem, consider the $\| \cdot \|_2$ setting, then example Exercise 6.3.5. in Vershynin's High Dimensional Probability states that for a $m \times n$ constant matrix $B$, $Z \sim N(0,I)$, that
$$
P( \| BZ\|_{2} \ge C \| B \|_F + t) \le \exp \left ( -\frac{ct^2}{\| B \|^2_\text{op}}\right)
$$
where the subscript $F$ is the frobenius norm. Choosing $B = \sqrt{\Sigma}$ yields
$$
P( \| X \|_{2} \ge C \sqrt{\text{Tr}(\Sigma)} + t) \le \exp \left ( -\frac{ct^2}{\|\Sigma\|^2_{\text{op}}}\right),
$$
so that with high probability $\| X \|_2 \le C\sqrt{\text{Tr}(\Sigma)}$. In the worst case, $\Sigma = I$ and we get back the standard bound $\| X \|_2 \le C\sqrt{p}$, but for many problems of interest $\Sigma$ has a nice structure that makes the first bound more useful.

Is there a similar bound that generalizes the $\sqrt{\log p}$ bound? Ideally it would involve the trace, $\|X\|_{\max} \stackrel{?}{\le} C \sqrt{\log \text{Tr}(\Sigma)}$.

Note also that all results mentioned hold more generally for subGaussian random variables (with different universal constants), but for simplicity I am just looking at the Gaussian case.

**An update**: I have found a related dimension free result, Lemma 2.3 of this [paper by Van Handel](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.05003.pdf) states that for $X_1,\dots, X_n$ be not necessarily independent subGaussian random variables with subGaussian norm $\sigma_i$, then
$$
E [\max_{i \le n} X_i] \le C \max_{i \le n} \sigma_{(i)} \sqrt{\log(i+1)}
$$
where $\sigma_{(1)} \ge \sigma_{(2)} \ge \dots \sigma_{(n)}$  are the ordered subGaussian norms. If the $X$'s are independent Gaussian there is a matching lower bound.

Comment: I would suspect strongly that $\mathrm{tr}(\Sigma) \asymp p$ since it is the sum of eigenvalues, so unless $\Sigma$ is very non-singular (has many eigenvalues close to zero, or zero even), the trace should be at least a constant times $p$ (this is true if we assume, say, that the $10\%$ greatest eigenvalues are at least a universal constant).

Comment: @WilliamM. I'm not entirely sure why that matters as far as finding a dim-free bound for the max-norm. Are you saying the desired log-trace dependence is unlikely to be true ? I'm not sure I see that from your comment though

Comment: You are saying you ideally want $\|X\|_\infty \leq c \sqrt{\log \mathrm{tr}(\Sigma)},$ this becomes $c \sqrt{\log p}$ in many cases, which is what you already got. This will be true provided $\Sigma$ has a universal fraction (however small but positive this fraction may be) of its eigen values above a universal constant (again, however small). In other words, even if you do get the bound $c \sqrt{\log \mathrm{tr} \Sigma},$ it will reduce to what you already have unless $\Sigma$ is highly non-singular (in which case you really are dealing with a much smaller dimensional Gaussian).

Comment: @WilliamM. you are correct, but again this has nothing to do with finding the dim-free bound